# Play String data. (Play string value as audio)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, avaudioplayer

like when we want to play audio file in android application we use media player and get audio file from raw folder and we simply play it. what i want to do is like i want to play audio from string data. example : 
String value = "Hello sir";

i want to play this string "hello sir" as audio.

Comment: Search "TextToSpeech"

Comment: @SergeyGlotov thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextToSpeech`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextToSpeech mTextToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    mTextToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
                    speak("Hello sir");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void speak(String text) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            textToSpeechGreater21(text);
        } else {
            textToSpeechUnder20(text);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void textToSpeechUnder20(String text) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
        mTextToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void textToSpeechGreater21(String text) {
        String utteranceId = this.hashCode() + "";
        mTextToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId);
    }
}
```